# Would a "Vote these questions up" chat room make sense?

Tags: discussion, chat

Since we don't have a lot of active voters, I was wondering if a chat room that's the opposite of "Vote to close" would make sense.  Just as people post links in Vote to Close to what they consider to be close-worthy questions, people could post links to questions they think are particularly good in this new chat.  It would be a way for people to highlight questions they think deserve more votes, which would be beneficial in distinguishing the really good question from the ones that get just a couple of upvotes.

Comment: So the consensus seems to be that this is a bit of a bad idea, which I can totally agree with.  Now if you'd all just vote more...

Comment: I thought it was a good *question*, and hence upvoted. But my thoughts on 'rooms designed to cause voting' are below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm. How many people hang around in the Vote to Close room? I bet most of them are active voters too, so I'm dubious about how much impact it would really have (+ that's one more chat room to idle in)

There's something that just feels a bit off about having a "Vote Up" room but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I agree that it seems a bit off, but I wanted to see what others felt.

Comment: +1 If those inhabiting the room are the regulars, who are also mostly good voters, isn't that kind of like preaching to the choir? Seems really pointless to me.

Answer (score 4):

The way I understand V-T-C is that close votes age out, so after 4 days (or whatever time it is), the close count gets reset, so it "helps" if there is some mechanism to say "hey, my close votes will be wasted if you don't help out.  Take a look, and if you agree or not, that's fine, just take a look".  Upvotes never age out... if you like something, just up-vote it yourself and congratulate yourself and move on.

Comment: Yeah, this is one reason why I think a "Vote this Up" chat is a bit of a funny idea.  But since there aren't a lot of people who vote at all, I wanted to raise the idea.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to mind is how this is going to be moderated. Who's to say that a particular question is really good or not? I'm afraid a chat room is just going to be abused (in the sense of people "plug"ing their own questions or questions from friends etc).

I think that we rather should focus on upvoting questions, as upvoting questions IS the way of showing the users what the community likes/dislikes. Upvoting questions isnt there just to give the OP some reputation IMHO..

Comment: I think if there were a "Vote this Up" room, it would be the regulars from The Comms Room and Vote to Close who would use it, and they'd all be good at self-moderating.  Also, it'd just be for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

To be dead honest, I'm already uncomfortable with the Vote To Close room. Downvote and upvote-specific communities have the slight scent of [Digg Bury Brigade](http://www.wired.com/techbiz/people/news/2007/03/72835) to me, although I know that is not the intention here.

(So that's a "no" from my POV.)

Comment: Almost non of the closed questions are disputed so you shouldn't feel uneasy about the vtc room. Bear in mind that only 210 people on SF have vtc privilege and only about 20 of them regularly use it. The vtc room is an important janitorial tool for bringing questions that are off topic and better served elsewhere or are poor quality etc to the janitors attention.

Comment: Vote to Close works well - questions come in around the clock it's nice to be able to have the crappy ones you missed while sleeping (or - god forbid - working!) pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I think [The Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) already serves this purpose to some extent -- If you stumble on a great question & post it there it will collect upvotes.

That's also a good place to bring "Does anyone have any idea WTF this person is on about?" questions -- If someone can make sense of what they're trying to ask we'll usually fix up the question and get it an answer.  If it's really beyond hope it'll get closed

Comment: I think The Comms Room is working well for figuring out what some oddly-phrased questions really mean, and for regulars flagging exceptionally good questions for extra votes.  I don't think it'd be a good idea to use it for people to constantly post their "top 3 questions of the day" lists.

Comment: @Ward definitely not - I don't think any room is a good place for that really.

Answer (score 1):

A good use for a room like that might be to create a curated list of great questions for a "best of SF" twitter feed to use with community advertising. And if a question was good enough for that then it would be good enough to vote up.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a comment for this.  Wait...